# Expectation of a function of uniform R.V.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a uniform R.V. defined over the interval [-100,100]. Let $g(X) = e^-\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$, where $\mu = 0$, $\sigma = 10$. This is a Gaussian function and it is essentially zero outside the range [-100,100].

I want to find $E[g(x)]= \int g(x) f(x) dx$. Yes, I know that this is a Guassian integral whose value is $\sqrt{2\sigma^2 \pi}$ but I want to derive this as a function of a uniform r.v. The problem is that $f(x) = \frac{1}{100}$ since it is a uniform r.v. Well what if I now extend the interval to [-200,200], then I'll be multiplying by $\frac{1}{200}$. What if I extend to [-inf,inf] then I'll be dividing by zero?

Clearly something is wrong in this approach as it will never lead to same answer as finding the value through standard calculus. What is missing?

Comment: Have you tried $E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)F(x)~ dx$

Comment: The thing is, F(x) for a uniform is 1/(b-a). Now if I extend my range to -inf to inf, then 1/(b-a) is going to be zero. So that seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Eg(X)=\frac 1 {100}\int_{-100}^{100}e^{-x^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}dx=\frac {\sigma} {10}\int_{-10}^{100}e^{-y^{2}/2}dx=\sqrt {2\pi} [\Phi(10)-\Phi(-10)]$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function.

Comment: Isn't $\Phi[10]$ and $\Phi[-10]$ essentially zero? Then the answer is zero? That doesn't look correct.

Comment: @student1 You are confusing $\Phi$ with the pdf $\phi$. It is not true that $\Phi(10)-\Phi(-10)=0$.

Comment: Ok, but what if I extend the range to [-inf,inf]? Then that fraction before the integral is 0 ($\frac{1}{b-a}=\frac{1}{2\infty}=0$). But we know that the answer is not zero?

Comment: There is no such thing  as a  uniform random variable $X$ on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: To expand on @geetha290krm the CDF of a uniform r.v. is divergent if $X \in (-\infty, \infty)$